# Exponential of an integral inequality true?

Tags: integration, calculus-of-variations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5d2d.png)I was wondering if the inequality is true. I tried expanding the exponential (on the left) so that I have a power series in the integral of I(C), which is an increasing function. I am not sure how to employ Cauchy-Schwarz or Chebyshev's sum inequality to get an upper bound.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOE65.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHMlQ.png]

Comment: Which of the functions $t\mapsto I(C(t))$ or $t\mapsto \int_a^t I(C(s))\text{d} s$ is increasing? Is $C_{50} >0$? What do you mean when you write "$I(C(t))$ has a global minimum"?

Comment: The integral to t is the increasing function; C50>0; Of all C(t) with area AUC, the one that minimizes the integral from a to b of C50/(C(t) + C50) is C(t)=AUC/(b-a). I should have used a different dummy variable in the definition of I(C(t)) so that t isn't repeated. I will fix this.

Comment: If your inequality is true, I bet it can be proved using some sort of convexity argument. Indeed, $\phi (t) = \int_a^t I[C](s)\text{d} s = \int_a^t k_{\text{out}}\ \left( \int_a^s \frac{C_{50}}{C(\sigma) + C_{50}}\ \text{d} \sigma\right)\ \text{d} s$ is the integral function of an increasing function, hence it is convex; moreover the exponential function is increasing and convex, thus $e^{\phi (t)}$ is increasing and convex.

Comment: I corrected the definition of I(C) - too many integrals. Sorry!  Note: The inequality is true when C(t) = AUC/(b-a); in fact, it is an equality.  I also tried the convexity of exponential argument (exponential of integral <=  integral of exponential), but I can't see how it will work.